# How can I create a histogram of appearances of values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, count, histogram

Using python 2.6:

I have a dictionary where each key contains a list of values.

I want to look at all the values in the dictionary and tally how many times each appears across all keys.

I have been looking at itervalues() or

```
for value in dictionary.values():
```

for a start, and also the .count() function, but I need to return a histogram.

for example:

```
print dictionary
```

would return

```
{'test' : ['spam', 'eggs', 'cheese', 'spam'], 'test2' : ['spam', 'cheese', 'goats']}
```

and I want something to tell me:

```
{'spam' : 3, 'eggs' : 1, 'cheese': 2, 'goats' : 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the list of values and add them to a new dictionary by incrementing one by one.

```
# start with an empty output dictionary
out = {}

# iterate through the keys in the dictionary
for key in p:
   # iterate through the values in the sublist
   for val in p[key]:
      # check to see if we've seen this one before
      if not out.has_key(val):
         # if not, start it out at 0
         out[val] = 0

      # increment by one because we've seen it once more
      out[val] += 1

print out
```

Comment: Great! so far at least. It appears the count is off somewhat, however, just for a few of the values. Let me look into why.

Comment: this appears to be an issue with a previous part of the program. your counter does work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'test' : ['spam', 'eggs', 'cheese', 'spam'], 'test2' : ['spam', 'cheese', 'goats']}
c = Counter(sum(d.values(), []))
# or c = Counter(x for a in d.values() for x in a)
print c.most_common()

## [('spam', 3), ('cheese', 2), ('eggs', 1), ('goats', 1)]
```

For python 2.6 use [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/).

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about this one.

Comment: counter is new in 2.7, im using 2.6 hence asking.

Comment: @Friloc: just get it [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I like Counter.  Not so sure about using side-effect list comprehensions.