# python dictionary count of unique values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem with counting distinct values for each key in Python.

I have a dictionary d like

```
[{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"}, {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]
```

I need to print number of distinct values per each key individually.

That means I would want to print

```
abc 3
xyz 1
pqr 4
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: You mean you have a list of dictionaries? Or is it reproduced incorrectly?

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's at best a list of dictionaries (which only contain one key/value pair) - really? What kind of a data structure is that? And I'm guessing it's actually `[{"abc": "movies"}, ...`, right?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thats right.  Sorry for the mistake in representation

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303788/how-can-i-create-a-histogram-of-appearances-of-values-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Over 6 years after answering, someone pointed out to me I misread the question. While my original answer (below) counts unique *keys* in the input sequence, you actually have a different [count-distinct problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-distinct_problem); you want to count *values per key*.

To count unique values per key, *exactly*, you'd have to collect those values into sets first:

```
values_per_key = {}
for d in iterable_of_dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        values_per_key.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
counts = {k: len(v) for k, v in values_per_key.items()}
```

which for your input, produces:

```
>>> values_per_key = {}
>>> for d in iterable_of_dicts:
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         values_per_key.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
...
>>> counts = {k: len(v) for k, v in values_per_key.items()}
>>> counts
{'abc': 3, 'xyz': 1, 'pqr': 4}
```

We can still wrap that object in a `Counter()` instance if you want to make use of the additional functionality this class offers, see below:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(counts)
Counter({'pqr': 4, 'abc': 3, 'xyz': 1})
```

The downside is that if your input iterable is very large the above approach can require a lot of memory. In case you don't need *exact* counts, e.g. when orders of magnitude suffice, there are other approaches, such as a [hyperloglog structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) or other algorithms that 'sketch out' a count for the stream.

This approach requires you install a 3rd-party library. As an example, the [`datasketch` project](http://ekzhu.com/datasketch/) offers both [HyperLogLog](http://ekzhu.com/datasketch/hyperloglog.html) and [MinHash](http://ekzhu.com/datasketch/minhash.html). Here's a HLL example (using the `HyperLogLogPlusPlus` class, which is a recent improvement to the HLL approach):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datasketch import HyperLogLogPlusPlus

counts = defaultdict(HyperLogLogPlusPlus)

for d in iterable_of_dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        counts[k].update(v.encode('utf8'))
```

In a distributed setup, you could use [Redis to manage the HLL counts](http://antirez.com/news/75).

---

*My original answer*:

Use a [`collections.Counter()` instance](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), together with some chaining:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.keys() for e in d))
```

This ensures that dictionaries with more than one key in your input list are counted correctly.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d = [{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"}, {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.keys() for e in d))
Counter({'pqr': 5, 'abc': 3, 'xyz': 1})
```

or with multiple keys in the input dictionaries:

```
>>> d = [{"abc":"movies", 'xyz': 'music', 'pqr': 'music'}, {"abc": "sports", 'pqr': 'movies'}, {"abc": "music", 'pqr': 'sports'}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.keys() for e in d))
Counter({'pqr': 5, 'abc': 3, 'xyz': 1})
```

A `Counter()` has additional, helpful functionality, such as the [`.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) that lists elements and their counts in reverse sorted order:

```
for key, count in counts.most_common():
    print '{}: {}'.format(key, count)

# prints
# 5: pqr
# 3: abc
# 1: xyz
```

Comment: This is very cool but it doesn't solve the problem. It was asked for unique values. `pqr` is returning 5 but should be returning 4. cc: @user1189851

Comment: @SeanDunford: interesting; it indeed looks like I misread the question at the time, not sure why the OP then accepted my answer. I'll update it to add a uniques-per-key count too.

Comment: @SeanDunford: there, added both the straight-forward counts using sets, and what to do when you have way more data than memory.

Answer (score 5):

No need of using counter. You can achieve in this way:

```
# input dictionary
d=[{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"}, {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]

# fetch keys
b=[j[0] for i in d for j in i.items()]

# print output
for k in list(set(b)):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(k, b.count(k))
```

Comment: This is even faster, than using with counter.

Comment: yes, Counter has some performance issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing--a list with multiple values for each key--would be better visualized by something like this:

```
{'abc': ['movies', 'sports', 'music'],
 'xyz': ['music'],
 'pqr': ['music', 'movies', 'sports', 'news']
}
```

In that case, you have to do a bit more work to insert:

1. Lookup key to see if it already exists

   - If doesn't exist, create new key with value `[]` (empty list)
2. Retrieve value (the list associated with the key)
3. Use `if value in` to see if the value being checked exists in the list
4. If the new value isn't in, `.append()` it

This also leads to an easy way to count the total number of elements stored:

```
# Pseudo-code
for myKey in myDict.keys():
    print "{0}: {1}".format(myKey, len(myDict[myKey])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = [{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"},
... {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, 
... {"pqr":"sports"}]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(key for dic in d for key in dic.keys())
>>> counts
Counter({'pqr': 5, 'abc': 3, 'xyz': 1})
>>> for key in counts:
...     print (key, counts[key])
...
xyz 1
abc 3
pqr 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a collections.Counter. Assuming that you have a list of one item dictionaries...

```
from collections import Counter
listOfDictionaries = [{'abc':'movies'}, {'abc':'sports'}, {'abc':'music'},
    {'xyz':'music'}, {'pqr':'music'}, {'pqr':'movies'},
    {'pqr':'sports'}, {'pqr':'news'}, {'pqr':'sports'}]
Counter(list(dict)[0] for dict in zzz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @akashdeep solution which uses the set but gives a wrong result because is not counting for the "distinct" requirement mentioned in the question (`pqr` should be 4, not 5).

```
# dictionary
d=[{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"}, {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]

# merged dictionary
c = {}
for i in d:
    for k,v in i.items():
        try:
            c[k].append(v)
        except KeyError:
            c[k] = [v]

# counting and printing
for k,v in c.items():
    print "{0}: {1}".format(k, len(set(v)))
```

This will give the correct:

```
xyz: 1
abc: 3
pqr: 4
```