# Surprising results with Python timeit: Counter() vs defaultdict() vs dict()

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter, timeit, defaultdict

I obtained very surprising results with timeit, can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong ? I am using Python 2.7.

This is the contents of file speedtest_init.py:

```
import random

to_count = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(60)]
```

These are the contents of speedtest.py:

```
__author__ = 'BlueTrin'

import timeit

def test_init1():
    print(timeit.timeit('import speedtest_init'))

def test_counter1():
    s = """\
    d = defaultdict(int);
    for i in speedtest_init.to_count:
        d[i] += 1
    """
    print(timeit.timeit(s, 'from collections import defaultdict; import speedtest_init;'))

def test_counter2():
    print(timeit.timeit('d = Counter(speedtest_init.to_count);', 'from collections import Counter; import speedtest_init;'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_init1()
    test_counter1()
    test_counter2()
```

The console output is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Dev/codility/chlorum2014/speedtest.py
2.71501962931
65.7090444503
91.2953839048

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think by default timeit() runs 1000000 times the code, so I need to divide the times by 1000000, but what is surprising is that the Counter is slower than the defaultdict().

Is that expected ?

EDIT:

Also using a dict is faster than a defaultdict(int):

```
def test_counter3():
    s = """\
    d = {};
    for i in speedtest_init.to_count:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] += 1
    """
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s, setup='from collections import defaultdict; import speedtest_init;')
```

this last version is faster than the defaultdict(int) meaning that unless you care more about readability you should use the dict() rather than the defaultdict().

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is expected; the `Counter()` *constructor* uses `Counter.update()` which uses `self.get()` to load initial values rather than rely on `__missing__`.

Moreover, the `defaultdict` `__missing__` factory is handled entirely in C code, especially when using another type like `int()` that is itself implemented in C. The `Counter` source is pure Python and as such the `Counter.__missing__` method requires a Python frame to execute.

Because `dict.get()` is still handled in C, the constructor approach is the faster approach for a `Counter()`, provided you use the same trick `Counter.update()` uses and alias the `self.get` lookup as a local first:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> to_count = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(60)]
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in to_count: c[i] += 1',
...               'from collections import Counter; from __main__ import to_count; c = Counter()',
...               number=10000)
0.2510359287261963
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in to_count: c[i] = c_get(i, 0) + 1',
...               'from collections import Counter; from __main__ import to_count; c = Counter(); c_get = c.get',
...               number=10000)
0.20978617668151855
```

Both `defaultdict` and `Counter` are helpful classes built for their functionality, not their performance; not relying on the `__missing__` hook can be faster still:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in to_count: d[i] = d_get(i, 0) + 1',
...               'from __main__ import to_count; d = {}; d_get = d.get',
...               number=10000)
0.11437392234802246
```

That's a regular dictionary using an aliased `dict.get()` method for maximum speed. But then you'll also have to re-implement the bag behaviour of `Counter`, or the `Counter.most_common()` method. The `defaultdict` use cases go way beyond counting.

In Python 3.2, updating a `Counter()` got a speed boost by adding a C library that handles this case; see [issue 10667](http://bugs.python.org/issue10667). Testing on Python 3.4, the `Counter()` constructor now beats the aliased `dict.get` case:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('Counter(to_count)',
...               'from collections import Counter; from __main__ import to_count',
...               number=100000)
0.8332311600097455
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in to_count: d[i] = d_get(i, 0) + 1',
...               'from __main__ import to_count; d = {}; d_get = d.get',
...               number=100000)
0.961191965994658
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

(Note: to get a meaningful timing result the number of iterations was increased from 10k to 100k; so if you compare these against the `dict.get()` case above you need to take the timing there times ten, at 1.144 seconds).

Comment: As of 2020 using python 3.7 >= this is no longer the case - Counter is faster

Comment: @bones.felipe please read the whole answer. The question was about Python 2.7, but I mention that as of *Python 3.2* Counter is faster, so as of 2012 (8 years ago).