# Speeding-up "for-loop" in image analysis when iterations are up to 40,000

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, numpy, equality

The details of the prerequisites of this code are quite long so I'll try my best to summarize. WB/RG/BYColor is the base image, FIDO is an overlay of this base image which is applied to it. S_wb/rg/by are the final output images. WB/RG/BYColor are the same size as FIDO.

**For each unique element in FIDO, we want to calculate the average color of that region within the base images**. The below **code does this, but** as numFIDOs is very large (up to 40,000), this takes a **long time**.

The averages are computed for the three separate RGB channels.

```
sX=200
sY=200
S_wb = np.zeros((sX, sY))
S_rg = np.zeros((sX, sY))
S_by = np.zeros((sX, sY))
uniqueFIDOs, unique_counts = np.unique(FIDO, return_counts=True) 
numFIDOs = uniqueFIDOs.shape  
for i in np.arange(0,numFIDOs[0]):
    Lookup = FIDO==uniqueFIDOs[i]
    # Get average of color signals for this FIDO
    S_wb[Lookup] = np.sum(WBColor[Lookup])/unique_counts[i]
    S_rg[Lookup] = np.sum(RGColor[Lookup])/unique_counts[i]
    S_by[Lookup] = np.sum(BYColor[Lookup])/unique_counts[i]
```

This takes about 7.89 seconds to run, no so long, but this will be included in another loop, so it builds up!

I have tried vectorization (shown below) but I couldn't do it

```
FIDOsize = unique_counts[0:numFIDOs[0]:1]
Lookup = FIDO ==uniqueFIDOs[0:numFIDOs[0]:1]
S_wb[Lookup] = np.sum(WBColor[Lookup])/FIDOsize
S_rg[Lookup] = np.sum(RGColor[Lookup])/FIDOsize
S_by[Lookup] = np.sum(BYColor[Lookup])/FIDOsize
```

error in array size matching

Comment: You may want to make your code self-contained and add runtime measurements.

Comment: is it possible to attach variables? To make it self-contained I would have to copy many many lines of code into here.

Comment: One thing that is apparent is that you could turn 7 slow lookups into one:  `indexarr = FIDO==uniqueFIDOs[i]`.  Then just do `S[indexarr] = np.sum(Color[indexarr])/FIDOsize`.  You could also probably simplify the FIDOsize computation by using `uniqueFIDOs, unique_counts = np.unique(FIDO, return_counts=True)` and then just `FIDOsize = unique_counts[i]`.

Comment: When it comes to (time-critical) image analysis, something like [pyCUDA](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) could be worth a look - at least, for some application cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already implemented in Scipy, so you could do:

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import mean as labeled_mean

labels = np.arange(FIDO.max()+1, dtype=int)
S_wb = labeled_mean(WBColor, FIDO, labels)[FIDO]
S_rg = labeled_mean(RGColor, FIDO, labels)[FIDO]
S_by = labeled_mean(BYColor, FIDO, labels)[FIDO]
```

This is assuming that `FIDO` contains relatively small integers. If this is not the case you can transform it through `np.unique(FIDO, return_inverse=True)`.

This simple code is about 1000x faster than the original, for 200x200 images and `FIDO` containing random integers from zero to 40,000.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can avoid this error? `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38890) (40000) `

Comment: @WBM - It's hard for me to reproduce this error. Could you give some details, like on which line this error occurs and what are the shapes of the arrays involved? For testing I used myself: `FIDO = np.random.randint(40000, size=(200, 200))` and `WBColor = np.random.rand(200, 200)`.

Comment: FIDO is 200x200  , WBColor is 200x200 (-1 to 1). This is my current error
`S_wb = labeled_mean(WBColor, FIDO, labels)[FIDO] 
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: @WBM - If `FIDO` already contains integers you can do a `FIDO = FIDO.astype(int)` and then it should work. If the elements in `FIDO` are anything other than integers you could first do `notused, FIDO_int = np.unique(FIDO, return_inverse=True)` followed by `FIDO_int.shape = (200, 200)` and use `FIDO_int` in place of `FIDO`.

Answer (score 5):

By my timing, this is about 10 times faster than your original method. I tested with these arrays:

```
import numpy as np

sX=200
sY=200

FIDO = np.random.randint(0, sX*sY, (sX, sY))
WBColor = np.random.randint(0, sX*sY, (sX, sY))
RGColor = np.random.randint(0, sX*sY, (sX, sY))
BYColor = np.random.randint(0, sX*sY, (sX, sY))
```

This is the part I timed:

```
import collections

colors = {'wb': WBColor, 'rg': RGColor, 'by': BYColor}
planes = colors.keys()
S = {plane: np.zeros((sX, sY)) for plane in planes}

for plane in planes:
    counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    sums = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for (i, j), f in np.ndenumerate(FIDO):
        counts[f] += 1
        sums[f] += colors[plane][i, j]
    for (i, j), f in np.ndenumerate(FIDO):
        S[plane][i, j] = sums[f]/counts[f]
```

Probably because even though looping in Python is slow, this traverses the data less.

Note, the original version gets faster if there are a small number of unique values in `FIDO`. This takes roughly the same time for most cases.

Comment: instead of `collections.defaultdict(int)` you could use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: [defaultdict is faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict). Also, for this application, most of the time is actually spent traversing the data, so I wanted to be able to update the sum rather than just count.

Comment: In python3 `Counter` is like twice as fast as `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: Python 3.5 on my MacBook Air: `Counter`: 530 ms, `defaultdict(int)`: 420 ms.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not optimal, because you scan the all image for each region in `FIDO`. Better approach is to group the pixels of each region and calculate the means first. `pandas`give nice tools for such computations (just on one canal here). Then you span the means on the regions :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd     
sX=200
sY=200
Nreg=sX*sY
WBColor=np.random.randint(0,256,(sX,sY))
FIDO=np.random.randint(0,Nreg,(sX,sY))


def oldloop():
    S_wb = np.zeros((sX, sY))
    uniqueFIDOs, unique_counts = np.unique(FIDO, return_counts=True) 
    numFIDOs = uniqueFIDOs.shape 
    for i in np.arange(0,numFIDOs[0]):
        Lookup = FIDO==uniqueFIDOs[i]
        S_wb[Lookup] = np.sum(WBColor[Lookup])/unique_counts[i]
    return S_wb

def newloop():
    index=pd.Index(FIDO.flatten(),name='region')
    means= pd.DataFrame(WBColor.flatten(),index).groupby(level='region').mean()
    lookup=np.zeros(Nreg)
    lookup[means.index]=means.values
    return lookup[FIDO]
```

in this case, this is about 200 times faster :

```
In [32]: np.allclose(oldloop(),newloop())
Out[32]: True

In [33]: %timeit -n1 oldloop()
1 loops, best of 3: 3.92 s per loop

In [34]: %timeit -n100 newloop()
100 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop
```

**EDIT**

An other cool modern approach is to use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/). You write (very) basic python code running at nearly C speed :

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def numbaloops():
    counts=np.zeros(Nreg)
    sums=np.zeros(Nreg)
    S = np.empty((sX, sY))
    for x in range(sX):
        for y in range(sY):
            region=FIDO[x,y]
            value=WBColor[x,y]
            counts[region]+=1
            sums[region]+=value
    for x in range(sX):
        for y in range(sY):
            region=FIDO[x,y]
            S[x,y]=sums[region]/counts[region]
    return S
```

You are now about 4000 times faster :

```
In [45]: np.allclose(oldloop(),numbaloops())
Out[45]: True

In [46]: %timeit -n1000 numbaloops()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: You can merge the last two sets of loops in the numba solution

Comment: @chthonicdaemon : Thanks. I take it into account, there are only two loops now, for an another 2 factor improvement.

Comment: @B. M. I receive this error with Pandas method:
`>>> means=pd.DataFrame(WBColor.flatten(),index).groupby(level='region').mean() .....code cut out.....
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1055, in _get_grouper
    raise ValueError('level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex')
ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex`

Comment: It seems to be a version bug  (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4014). `level=0` instead is probably a good patch here.

Comment: @B. M.
How can I convert the pandas object `means.index` into an array of integers? 
`lookup[means.index]=means.values
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: the best is to update your installation : pip install pandas --upgrade.
pdmeans.index.values return this array in pandas 0.15.2 .

Comment: @B. M. now working on pandas 0.17.0, and I still receive this error

Comment: have you tried  `lookup[pdmeans.index.values]=pdmeans.values` ?

Answer (score 4):

As @lejlot suggested before, the code is quite hard to vectorize. It cannot be run in parallel, unless you know which pixels belong to each FIDO in advance. I don't know if you call FIDO to superpixels, but I do usually work with this kind of problems, and the best solution I've found so far is as follows:

- Flatten the data:

  ```
  data = data.reshape(-1, 3)
  labels = FIDO.copy()
  ```

  Here `data` is your `(Width, Height, 3)` image, rather than the separate 3 vectors that you have. It gets flattened to `(Width * Height, 3)`.
- Relabel FIDO to `0..N-1` range, where `N`=num unique FIDO:

  ```
  from skimage.segmentation import relabel_sequential

  labels = relabel_sequential(labels)[0]
  labels -= labels.min()
  ```

  The above, from `scikit-image`, transforms your FIDO array to the `[0, N-1]` range, which is much easier to work with later.
- Last, code in **cython** a simple function to calculate the mean for each of the FIDO;s (as they are ordered from 0 to N, you can do it in a 1D array with length N):

  ```
  def fmeans(double[:, ::1] data, long[::1] labels, long nsp):
      cdef long n,  N = labels.shape[0]
      cdef int K = data.shape[1]
      cdef double[:, ::1] F = np.zeros((nsp, K), np.float64)
      cdef int[::1] sizes = np.zeros(nsp, np.int32)
      cdef long l, b
      cdef double t

      for n in range(N):
          l = labels[n]
          sizes[l] += 1

          for z in range(K):
              t = data[n, z]
              F[l, z] += t

      for n in range(nsp):
          for z in range(K):
              F[n, z] /= sizes[n]

  return np.asarray(F)
  ```

You can call that function later (once compiled with cython), as simple as:

```
mean_colors = fmeans(data, labels.flatten(), labels.max()+1) # labels.max()+1 == N
```

The image of mean colors can then be recovered as:

```
mean_img = mean_colors[labels]
```

If you do not want to code in cython, `scikit-image` also provides bindings for this by using a graph structure and `networkx`, however is much slower:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_rag_mean_color.html

The above example contains the function calls you need to get an image with the average color of each superpixel as `labels1` (your FIDO).

**NOTE**: The cython approach is much faster, as instead of iterating the number of unique FIDO `N` and for each of them scan the image (size `M = Width x Height`) this only iterates the image ONCE. Thus, computational cost is in the order of `O(M+N)` rather than `O(M*N)` of your original approach.

---

Example test:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import relabel_sequential

sX=200
sY=200

FIDO = np.random.randint(0, sX*sY, (sX, sY))
data = np.random.rand(sX, sY, 3) # Your image
```

Flatten and relabel:

```
data = data.reshape(-1, 3)
labels = relabel_sequential(FIDO)[0]
labels -= labels.min()
```

Obtain mean:

```
>>> %timeit color_means = fmeans(data, labels.flatten(), labels.max()+1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 520 µs per loop
```

It takes **0.5ms** (half a millisecond) for a 200x200 image for:

```
print labels.max()+1 # --> 25787 unique FIDO
print color_means.shape # --> (25287, 3), the mean color of each FIDO
```

You can restore the image of mean colors using smart indexing:

```
mean_image = color_means[labels]
print mean_image.shape # --> (200, 200, 3)
```

I doubt you can get that speed with raw python approaches (or at least, I didn't find how).

Comment: Skimage 0.10 with "relabel_sequential"  doesn't seem to be available for my system (Linux7.0), unfortunately

Comment: `relabel_sequential` should be available in [scikit-image 0.10.x](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/api/api.html). To install it you can type `pip install scikit-image` in a linux terminal, or `conda install scikit-image` if you use anaconda. However, if you still need a pure python approach, @B.M.'s `pandas` option seems to be an appropiate choice.

Comment: I receive this error with pip installation `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.5`

Comment: @WBM Write `easy_install --upgrade pip` to upgrade `pip` (you might need to put a `sudo` before). Afterwards, try the command above to install `scikit-image` again.

Comment: @WBM Ups, that might be a type from copy paste. Try `sudo pip install scikit-image` (with or without sudo, depends on your configuration).

Comment: @imalunego `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-image in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning`

Comment: Try to upgrade it as the command suggests `pip install --upgrade scikit-image`.

Comment: no luck: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-06a7236fa202> in <module>()
----> 1 from skimage.segmentation import relabel_sequential

ImportError: cannot import name relabel_sequential`

Answer (score 3):

In short: **loops in python are slow**. You should do one of the following:

- vectorize (you tried it, but you claim "it does not work"), what do you mean but not work? Vectorization (if possible) always works
- switch to Cython, and declare iterator value to be `int`

Both above approaches base on the conversion of the bottle-neck loop into C-loop.

Comment: the function looks quite hard to vectorize, so you are probably left with the second option.