# Adding count to correct dictionary in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

I'm hoping this is an easy one for those masters of for loops and dictionary lookups...but every attempt has so far yielded duplication of the count.

So, to begin, I have two loops:

```
for location in locations:
    print(location.service_type)

for service_type in service_types:
    print(service_type)
```

First output:

```
library
railway_station
school
cinema
school
supermarket
fire_station
```

Second output:

```
{'field': 'bus_station', 'choice': 'Bus Station', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'car_park', 'choice': 'Car Park', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'cinema', 'choice': 'Cinema', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'dentist', 'choice': 'Dentist', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'doctor', 'choice': 'Doctor', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'fire_station', 'choice': 'Fire Station', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'garden', 'choice': 'Public Garden', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'hospital', 'choice': 'Hospital', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'leisure_centre', 'choice': 'Leisure Centre', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'library', 'choice': 'Library', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'public_service', 'choice': 'Public Service', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'railway_station', 'choice': 'Railway Station', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'school', 'choice': 'School', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'supermarket', 'choice': 'Supermarket', 'count': 0}
{'field': 'woodland', 'choice': 'Woodland', 'count': 0}
```

What would be the most efficient way to add 1 to the count every time the first for loop's output matches the 'field' value in the second list of dictionaries outputted from the second for loop  for each 'field'?

I've started with all manor of loops and lookups but nothing is really getting past understanding how to manipulate the two data structures together coherently. I'm just flat out stuck on this.

Expected output:

```
list_of_dicts = [
   {'field': 'bus_station', 'choice': 'Bus Station', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'car_park', 'choice': 'Car Park', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'cinema', 'choice': 'Cinema', 'count': 1}
   {'field': 'dentist', 'choice': 'Dentist', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'doctor', 'choice': 'Doctor', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'fire_station', 'choice': 'Fire Station', 'count': 1}
   {'field': 'garden', 'choice': 'Public Garden', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'hospital', 'choice': 'Hospital', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'leisure_centre', 'choice': 'Leisure Centre', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'library', 'choice': 'Library', 'count': 1}
   {'field': 'public_service', 'choice': 'Public Service', 'count': 0}
   {'field': 'railway_station', 'choice': 'Railway Station', 'count': 1}
   {'field': 'school', 'choice': 'School', 'count': 2}
   {'field': 'supermarket', 'choice': 'Supermarket', 'count': 1}
   {'field': 'woodland', 'choice': 'Woodland', 'count': 0}
]
```

My best attempt, which kind of works:

```
service_types = []

_list = []
for location in locations:
    _list.append(location.service_type)

for field, choice in fields:
    service_types.append({ 'field': field, 'choice': choice, 'count': 0 })

new_service_types = []

for service_type in service_types:
    new_service_types.append({ 'field': service_type['field'], 'choice': service_type['choice'], 'count': _list.count(service_type['field']) })
```

?

Comment: Why not have the `service_types` be a dictionary with the `field` as the key instead of using an array?

Comment: You already indicated this data was produced from Django queries. What queries were those? You can have the *database* produce this data for you instead.

Comment: @NickA it doesn't work when passing it back in the context.

Comment: @Michael Roberts, How did it turn out? What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up sticking with the above...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Cool. Counter is pretty great tool to have. All sorts of way to use it. And _significantly_ faster counting if you have any sizable task to accomplish see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict). Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Counter class
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html

`from collections import Counter`

It is very fast and very easy to use.
Although, it works best with iterables (as opposed to the way I wrap it in a list on line 4 here), the code sample will get you started.

(For instance, if you had access to a list of all `location.service_type` you could just do `Counter(list)` and boom. Done.

```
counter = Counter()
list_of_dicts = []
for location in locations:
    counter.update([location.service_type])
print(counter)

for service_type in service_types:
    if service_type in counter:
        service_types['count'] = counter[service_type]
#and because you have specific output reqs
for service_type in service_types:
    list_of_dicts.append(service_type)
```

Output:

```
{
   'cinema': 1,
   'fire_station': 1,
   'library': 1,
   'railway_station': 1,
   'school': 2,
   'supermarket': 1
}


[
   {'field': 'bus_station', 'choice': 'Bus Station', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'car_park', 'choice': 'Car Park', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'cinema', 'choice': 'Cinema', 'count': 1},
   {'field': 'dentist', 'choice': 'Dentist', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'doctor', 'choice': 'Doctor', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'fire_station', 'choice': 'Fire Station', 'count': 1},
   {'field': 'garden', 'choice': 'Public Garden', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'hospital', 'choice': 'Hospital', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'leisure_centre', 'choice': 'Leisure Centre', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'library', 'choice': 'Library', 'count': 1},
   {'field': 'public_service', 'choice': 'Public Service', 'count': 0},
   {'field': 'railway_station', 'choice': 'Railway Station', 'count': 1},
   {'field': 'school', 'choice': 'School', 'count': 2},
   {'field': 'supermarket', 'choice': 'Supermarket', 'count': 1},
   {'field': 'woodland', 'choice': 'Woodland', 'count': 0}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this simple loop:

```
for service_type in service_types:
    field = service_type['field']
    if field in locations:
        service_type['count'] += locations.count(field)

print(service_types)
```

The list `service_types` gives the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
from collections import Counter

# 1. count the occurrence of locations
cnt = Counter(lcn.service_type for lcn in locations)


# 2a. if you don't want a duplicate you can just do this
for st in service_types:
    st['count'] += cnt[st['field']]

# 2b. OR, if you do want a duplicate into a new list
new_list = [dict(st, count=(st['count'] + cnt[st['field']])) 
                for st in service_types]
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html) on the Counter class.