# Counting Numbers as String in Python

Tags: python, numbers, counter

I'm a python's newbie. I've been trying to count the number of times 1-9 appears in a list, but python doesn't count the number and always consider as 1, without adding more counting for the occurrencies of the number 1-9. Does anyone could help me understand why?

```
#code
for nmb in ls:
            if nmb is not ls:
                frstdic[nmb] = 1
            else:
                frstdic[nmb] = frstdic[nmb] + 1
      
        print (frstdic)
                       
#return

{'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 1, '8': 1, '9': 1}

# nmb is a string
```

Comment: Can you share a sample input and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: So you're saying you're surprised that `nmb is not ls` is always true?

Comment: @ChrisCharley That doesn't make much sense after `for nmb in ls:`. Plus it's not valid syntax. Python isn't *that* chatty :-)

Comment: You should check `if nmb not in frstdic:`. Or better yet use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @superb rain Yes, I didn't think that through very well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in your code (see the comments). Consider using a counter or a default dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

#1
frstdic = defaultdict(int)
for nmb in ls:
    frstdic[nmb] += 1

#2
frstdic = Counter(ls)
```

The counter approach is about 4 times slower on short sequences but seems more elegant to me.

Comment: @superbrain Even if the syntax error is fixed, there is also a logic error/

Comment: "counter approach is about 4 times slower"--isn't the counter approach actually faster?

Comment: @DarrylG No, according to `%timeit`.

Comment: @superbrain Actually, you are right. There is just a logic error. Never mind.

Comment: Ok. I thought maybe you meant the indentation error. What exactly did you %timeit?

Comment: @DYZ--interesting I obtained a faster time Counter using timeit in Jupyter notebook using Python 3.8.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801945/surprising-results-with-python-timeit-counter-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict) seems to also indicate (in the comments) that Counter was sped up in Python 3 so now it's faster than defaultdict (i.e. was slower in Python 2).

Comment: @DarrylG Counter seems to have a much higher init cost. For an empty input it takes me four times as long. At seven elements, it beat the defaultdict. For large numbers it was a lot faster (factor 1.7 with some data, factor 4 with other). So I'm guessing DYZ tested very short input.

Comment: @superbrain I tested it on a 10-element list. I agree it may be too short.

Comment: Hmm, for `list('1234567890')`, `Counter` is already factor 1.3 faster for me. Are you using some old Python?

Comment: @superbrain I use 3.6.10, and Counter is 4x slower. The performance somewhat equalizes at `list('1234567890'*10)`.